# Strange error message using the Parse command line tool

Tags: parse-platform, go

I'm trying to execute `parse download` with the Parse.com's command line tool and I'm getting this error message:

> Failed to download Cloud Code.
>
> Invalid checksum, try again

I can't explain anymore because this happened suddenly and there's not any documentation about that [but this piece of code](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-cli/blob/master/parsecmd/download.go).

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Without more information, it's hard to tell where the error might be. The code for verifying checksum appears to be sound, so it's likely that the file you've downloaded _actually_ doesn't match the checksum this code expects. Where the checksum is coming from isn't apparent from the linked file.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't tell anything else. Perhaps I could :(

Comment: You could always build your own "verbose" version from source, adding in logging at critical points. For example, you might output the expected and actual checksums to see if they match the file that has been downloaded.